# Sometimes Ubuntu Linux does not resume after suspend

Tags: suspend, resume

I have an Asus Vivobook F510UA laptop which has 16 GB of RAM and 12 GB of swap file. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS at this laptop and this laptop sometimes does not wake from suspend when I re-open the lid of the laptop. When this problem occurs, I have to press power button 10 seconds and power off the laptop and press it again to restart the laptop. If I have an unsaved file, it will be lost. This problem does not occur every time I suspend the laptop by closing the screen lid and re-opening it. I can not give an exact number, but I can say between once a week to once a month I face this problem. This problem existed at Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS too, upgrading to 22.04 did not solve the problem.

When I check at /var/log/kern.log file, I noticed that when suspend/resume works fine, these 3 lines are added to kern.log file:

```
Feb  1 16:35:23 X510UAR kernel: [ 3415.022934] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 68:89:75:01:6e:ec by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb  1 16:35:24 X510UAR kernel: [ 3415.424510] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb  1 16:35:24 X510UAR kernel: [ 3415.438767] Filesystems sync: 0.014 seconds
```

When suspend/resume fails, these 2 lines are added to kern.log:

```
Feb  1 14:43:14 X510UAR kernel: [40793.588293] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 68:89:75:01:6e:ec by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb  1 14:43:14 X510UAR kernel: [40793.976139] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

So there is no filesystem sync line when there will be a resume problem.

What could be the problem? I have swap file smaller than RAM size. Could that be the problem?

Which log files should I check more?

Thanks

UPDATE: I set swap size bigger than RAM size 1 month ago and today laptop did not resume after suspend. So this is not related to swap size. Also I noticed that, laptop did not sleep properly, when this problem occurs. When laptop sleeps as usual, laptop consumes about 0.5 W power. But this time it was consuming about 5.5 W power and did not resume. I guess laptop did not go to sleep when I try to sleep it, instead it drops a strange state, consumes a lot of power but hangs, and does not respond anything but pressing power 10 seconds to power off.

Comment: A good guess would be that the swap file should be at least the size of RAM for suspend/resume to work reliably.

Comment: I've already increased the swap size to 18 GB. But I need to wait at least 1 month to be sure, if this is the problem. Because sometimes, I don't get this problem as long as 1 month. If I will face again this problem with 18 GB swap size, I will be sure that swap size is not the problem.

Comment: I have seen some notebooks have issues with resume after a certain period of time has passed. When the hardware goes from sleep to “deep sleep”, power to the storage device is suspended. When this happens, the wake command is triggered but the in-memory operations operate before the storage device is ready for use. As a result, the machine hangs because it does not know what to do 

Comment: I have my laptop setup so such that reopening the lid alone doesn't resume. A short press of the power button is required to wake up. That said, maybe once or twice a year it doesn't wake up and I have to cold boot by holding power button for 10 seconds. All my applications auto-save so it doesn't bother me...

Comment: @matigo What is the solution for this case? If this is the case with this laptop, other OSes should have the same problem such as Windows and macOS. I don't use Windows frequently on this laptop, but when I use Windows, I never faced this problem. I use more often macOS (hackintosh) if I compare to Windows on this laptop, I haven't faced this problem too. Can you confirm this problem exists on some other laptops with Windows OS?

Comment: @coolman I do not use, nor have access to, any Windows-based machines. I’m simply sharing a pattern that I have seen with the corporate fleet of notebooks that run Ubuntu. Most are Dell and Lenovo, which have few issues. The Acer, HP, and Panasonic devices all have occasional hiccups. If I ever see a working solution to the deep sleep power loss issue, there will be many colleagues eager to buy me a coffee …

Comment: @matigo Thanks for your feedback. So you don't think this is related to swap with smaller than RAM size. Anyway, I will keep my swap size is bigger than RAM. If this will solve the problem, I will update this question. I feel like this problem is related with linux. Because I've never heard or experienced similar problem while using windows.